# Displaying a resource's tasks across multiple subprojects

Tags: ms-project, reporting, ms-project-2010

I am having a bit of an issue getting the kind of report that I want from MS Project 2010. To get some background on my project, I am creating a master scheduled using multiple templates. The templates are in their own project files, so they are subprojects of the master project. What I want to create is a report that shows which subprojects a resource in involved in. Basically I want to be able to give employees their schedule for a year. Is there a way to get such a report?

Comment: Projects are dynamic: resource assignments may change, employees may leave, or schedule may slip or just change. So, you would probably consider renewing this reporting maybe each month to your employees.

Answer (score 2):

This you can easily achieve using MS Excel, as Excel provides a good compatibility with Microsoft Project, so you can copy/paste all contents from Excel to MPP and vice versa.

Follow these steps:-

1. Add an extra column to all your sub-projects MPP and write the Project Name in that column, it should be same within that project and also unique for each sub-project MPP
2. Copy/paste all your sub-projects to an Excel sheet, place them one beneath the other (i.e. adding more rows), such that same columns are aligned. So while 'Resource' column of Sub-project A, should continue with the same column of  Sub-project B
3. Once all sub-projects are merged into a spreadsheet, apply a Pivot table to get which resource is allocated to which all projects over the specified period of time.

Comment: This is a semi-workable solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a resource pool?  If so, open the resource pool, add the Project column to show Resources, their assignments and which projects the assignments come from.

I would use the Project field in the Resource Usage view with a group on Name (resource field) and then Project (assignment field). Collapse the group to second level and there's your report.

Comment: I have too many tasks for this to be a workable solution.

Comment: Too many tasks for what to be a workable solution?  Resource pools?  Adding the project column is one step.  The Resource Usage view already shows resources and their assignments.

Comment: Yes, but each resource in my project has hundreds of tasks. I just want to show the top level project files that their task comes from in a short report.

Comment: I would use the Project field in the Resource Usage view with a group on Name (resource field) and then Project (assignment field).  Collapse the group to second level and there's your report.  But of course, if you don't have a Resource Pool - you're out of luck.

Comment: I do have a resource pool, this sounds like a good view to get what I want. Thank you.